# How do I make an entire <div> link darken on hover?

Tags: html, css

In my website, I have a div with some content in it, which links to another part of the page. The code is shown here with placeholders for the actual content. When the div is clicked, the page does scroll as intended, but I want the entire div to darken on hover, so it is more clear to the user. I am not completely sure how to do this with divs in CSS. How could I do this?

```html
<a href="#testing">
  <div class="w3-third">
    <img src="media\[image]" width="171" height="80">
    <h1>
      [title]
    </h1>
    <h3>
      [item]<br>
      [item]<br>
      [item]
    </h3>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#darkOnHover:hover {
  background-color: #383838 ;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<a href="#testing">
  <div class="w3-third" id="darkOnHover">
    <img src="media\[image]" width="171" height="80">
    <h1>
      [title]
    </h1>
    <h3>
      [item]<br>
      [item]<br>
      [item]
    </h3>
  </div>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in the hover selector. This matters because the space is the descendant selector in CSS

```
div.w3-third :hover{
background-color: #E3E3E3;
}
```

This means that only hovered descendants of `.w3-third` are affected by the rules. Remove the space.
check the example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/PTSkR/57/)

Answer (score 0):

use `:visited` CSS pseudo-class  -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

```css
a:visited > div:hover {
  filter:brightness(50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

```
div.w3-third:hover {
  filter:brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .w3-third {
      background: #216efc;
    }
    
    div.w3-third:hover {
      filter: brightness(50%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#testing">
    <div class="w3-third">
      <img src="media\[image]" width="171" height="80">
      <h1>
        [title]
      </h1>
      <h3>
        [item]<br> [item]
        <br> [item]
      </h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```